# How do I get log4net logging info in Global.asax that comes from another .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, error-handling, log4net

I have an .aspx page with some synchronous code that's taking a very long time to execute and is triggering a request timeout. For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger("test");
    log.Debug("Before thread sleep...");
    Thread.Sleep(99999999);
    log.Debug("After thread sleep.");
}
```

In my `Global.asax`, I've added some error handling that will e-mail out any exceptions:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    SendExceptionEmail(exception);
}
```

Problem is, in `Global.asax`, I only have access to the request and response and the exception that occurred, but not the output from the logger. How do I get access to this in `Global.asax`? Without it, I can't tell what piece of code is hanging the application without digging through the log files, which is a major chore to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'log' object is a static variable, and it is not correct to try to fetch it in Global.asax Application_Error(). Depending on the current thread in thread pool, you might get unpredictable values in it.
A more secure approach could be along with log.Debug() to insert some Debug data into HttpContext.Current.Items. Then you can access these items in Application_Error() method.
Context.Items are considered as thread-safe and are recommended for use in cases like this.

Comment: Thanks Tisho. Using `HttpContext.Current.Items` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to have log4net send the email for you using an email appender. See this example: http://sradack.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/have-log4net-send-email-when-error.html

Comment: Problem with this method is that it assumes you're hitting the `_logger.Error()` line. In my case, `InternalDoSomethingImportant()` is blocking the process long enough that it exceeds the ASP.NET default timeout. Except I don't know which one of my many method calls is doing the block.

Comment: In which case, record the action name in an httpcontext item before you execute it and include it in the error message?

Comment: Wouldn't I get an e-mail for each logger message then? For example, I'd get an e-mail for `Before thread sleep...` and `After thread sleep.`.

Comment: My approach would be this: use logger.Debug generously so you know what is happening on each thread; before you call the long running action store the method name and any other info you want in HttpContext.Items (it's per-thread request); in global error handler use logger.Error. But if you only want certain errors to send email, create a new log4net category for that appender or use log4net filter on your global error class (global.asax).

Comment: You would set the email appender to level="ERROR". Create a separate appender for level="DEBUG".